# simple count based on foreign key produces bad result

Tags: mysql, percona

I am helpless with following situation. Let me describe my trouble by three simple queries:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM table WHERE fk1_id = 15;
SELECT count(1) FROM table WHERE fk2_id = 1;
SELECT count(1) FROM table WHERE fk1_id = 15 AND fk2_id = 1;
```

Results: 460, 2791 and... 0 (zero)

In addition to that result depends from the time. After reboot of the engine - result is non-zero, some time later - become a zero. 
`RESET QUERY CACHE` - no impact.
`FLUSH TABLES` - yes, it's temporary fix a situation.
*table* is not locked based on `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`.

Engine:  5.6.26-74 Percona Mysql, *table*:

```
CREATE TABLE table (  fk1_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  fk2_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  KEY (fk1_id),  KEY (fk2_id),  CONSTRAINT c1 FOREIGN KEY (fk1_id) REFERENCES table2 (id),  CONSTRAINT c3 FOREIGN KEY (fk2_id) REFERENCES table3 (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

`EXPLAIN` of the query:

```
select_type: SIMPLE
type: index_merge
key: fk1_id,  fk2_id
rows: 441
Extra: Using intersect(fk1_id,  fk2_id); Using where; Using index
```

Workaround to produce good result is force ignoring index like in the following SQL:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM video IGNORE INDEX(fk1_id) WHERE fk1_id = 15 AND fk2_id = 1;
```

I will be grateful for the proposals how to proceed with the problem.

PS I have created schema and test data on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7727ee

Other illustration of irrelevant behavior:

```
SELECT count(fk1_id) FROM table WHERE fk1_id = 15 AND fk2_id = 1;
SELECT count(other_column_not_covered_by_index) FROM table WHERE fk1_id = 15 AND fk2_id = 1;
```

First SQL result: 0, second: 433.

Comment: Are you updating the table? That would explain why the result changes. I don't see a problem here. If you're getting `0`, it means there are no rows that have both `fk1_id = 15` and `fk2_id = 1` in the same row.

Comment: If I'm misunderstanding, can you show some sample table contents that are producing incorrect results?

Comment: thank you Barmar for your interest. there is almost warehouse-type table - records are not deleted and as I described - results are differ if I enforce no-index query or flush the tables.

Comment: @Seeghor7 Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem? Indexes should only affect the efficiency of the query, not the results. If it makes some other difference, you've found a bug in MySQL and should report it to them.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7727ee

Comment: FYI, you don't need `DROP TABLE` in sqlfiddle, it always starts with an empty DB. Unfortunately, it's getting an internal error when I try to run a query -- not sure why, but that seems to happen every now and then with sqlfiddle.

Comment: It's working now, and returning the correct answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d60c2/4

Comment: FYI, Percona is not the standard MySQL InnoDB engine. It could be a bug there.

Comment: I am getting a similar result when making a selection based on multiple indexed columns, whether they contain a FK constraint or not. It returns the correct number of results, then I query from a separate connection via a PHP script and run the query--zero results. When I run the query again on my original connection--zero results. Only two fixes have worked so far: 1. Remove the index. 2. Change WHERE {col} = {val} to WHERE {col} IN ('', {val}).  Bizarre!